# transition between two view controllers Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, menu, sprite-kit, segue

Good day!
I do have a problem with performSegueWithIdentifier: in my game.
There are two view controllers "MainMenu" and "GameViewContoller".
My game starts with MainMenu like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    self.scene = [Menu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    self.scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:self.scene];


    UILabel *startButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame), 100, 40)];
    startButton.text = @"Start";
    startButton.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"out" size:20];
//    startButton.position  = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    startButton.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    startButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//    startButton.fontSize  = 20;
//    startButton.name      = @"Start";

    [self.view addSubview: startButton];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *startTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(start)];

    [startButton addGestureRecognizer: startTap];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) start{

    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Game" sender:nil];
}
```

so my game is shutting down when `[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Game" sender:nil];`
my segues configured correct, there is a segue name "Game". Game is running if is not in test mode from Xcode if so i have an error and second controller is not presented.
Any ideas?[image: error]

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: there is no error messages (( just nothing.

Comment: segues changes without any errors if there is no scenes and SKView

Comment: also in simulator there is no errors, transition works

Comment: So the app crashes on `[vs performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Game" sender:nil]` but there isn't an error message????  You need to re-word your question, I really have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: add screen shot with error